# What is this chip? Labeled "Atmel MC3G-04KI78-5"

Tags: integrated-circuit, atmel

I am unable to find any detail nor a datasheet about this component... Any idea? Cheers

Comment: rule of thumb: this means you don't need it, and can't use it – throw it away. Source: I've hoarded to many "might need later" ICs during the first half of my life.

Comment: Thank you @Marcus Müller :)